# How to solve this diophantine equation: $x^2+2y^2=x^2y^2-2000$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, diophantine-equations

> Solve the following diophantine equation: $$x^2+2y^2=x^2y^2-2000$$

I tried this by adding and subtracting terms, but so far, no avail.

$(\pm 2y^2+4xy, \pm2xy)$

I don't know how to start either. Please give a hint.

Comment: I think, you mean $x,y\in\mathbb Z$

Comment: @lonestudent I think that is specified in the definition of diophantine eqns.

Comment: Yes, right. I thought there was odd degree in the equation.  So I wanted to ask if you need maybe only $ x, y\in \mathbb Z ^ {+} $:  All degrees are even  so it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tips:$$x^2+2y^2=x^2y^2-2000 \\ x^2y^2-x^2-2y^2=2000 \\ x^2y^2-x^2-2y^2+2=2002 \\ (x^2-2)(y^2-1)=2002$$

Comment: According to this, $x=\pm 12$;$y= \pm 4$, right?

Comment: @Crease it should be $x=\pm 4, y=\pm12$, a tiny mistake.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2=\dfrac{2(y^2-1+1001)}{y^2-1}=2+\dfrac{2002}{y^2-1}$$

$$y^2-1\le2002\iff y^2\le2003<45^2$$

$$\implies 2\le y\le44$$

Also $y^2-1$ must be odd and must divide $2002=2\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13$